# Grouping nodes with the same color near each other in graphviz

Tags: visualization, graphviz, graph-visualization

I have created a graph with networkx and have wrote the graph representation to a dot file to be displayed with graphviz. Now, the nodes have color attributes and I would like graphviz to place nodes with the same color closer to each other.

For example, if node "soccer" and node "football" both have color 'blue' then they should be close together, whereas node "baseball" with color 'green' would not be near nodes "soccer" and "football"

1. How can I get nodes with the same color to be drawn closer together in Graphviz; hence forming clusters of colors?

Thanks for all the help and let me know if you need more information :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use PyGraphviz to do the layout using dot with "clusters".
e.g.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, color='blue', style='filled')
G.add_node(2, color='red', style='filled')
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_node(3, color='blue',style='filled')
G.add_node(4, color='red',style='filled')
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,10)
G.add_path([10,20,30,40,50])

A = nx.to_agraph(G) # uses pygraphviz
red_nodes = [n for n,d in G.node.items() if d.get('color')=='red']
blue_nodes = [n for n,d in G.node.items() if d.get('color')=='blue']
A.add_subgraph(red_nodes, name = 'cluster1', color='red')
A.add_subgraph(blue_nodes, name = 'cluster2', color='blue')
A.write('colors.dot')
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('colors.png')
```

[image]